# adding an object into another object that is in another object

Tags: javascript, extend

Say that there are three objects, a note, a noteState, and history:

```
var note = {
    text: "hello new world"
}

var history = {}
var noteState = {}
```

how would i be able to add note into noteState, and then add noteState into history?

could i potentially do something like:

```
$.extend(noteState, {"note1": note});
$.extend(history, {"noteState1": noteState});
```

and if I were to refer back to it to grab the text from note, how would i go about doing so?

```
history.noteState1.note1.text  // ?
```

or is there another method to go about this? thank you!

Comment: When you use jQuery's .extend() method, you actually extend the object. For example: if you have obj1.text = "object one text"; and obj2.text = "object two text";, when you do $.extend(obj1, obj2), obj2's 'text' property will overwrite the obj1's. I hope I explain it well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply

```
var note = {
    text: "hello new world"
}

var history = {}
var noteState = {}

noteState.note = note;
history.noteState= noteState;
alert(history.noteState.note.text);//alerts hello new world
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and you don't have to use extend, simply set the properties. You don't even have to use distinct names, so following will do just fine :

```
noteState.note = note;
history.noteState = noteState;
```

Then, just as you wrote, you could use

```
 history.noteState.note.text
```

to retrieve the nested properties.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also use the *prototype* property to link your objects